# Why can I read with a BufferedReader in Java without Eventlistener

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, event-listener

I am comfortable with actionscript. When I wantet to have network access for example in air, I coded the request and waited for the EventListener to kick in.

At the moment I'm doing a java tutorial with the following android code (wrapped in a try/catch):

```
url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
String line = '';
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     // do something with the line
}
```

I don't get how this works.

Why is there no eventListener needed? If the code proceeds immidiately after the URL is requested, the URL may not been retrieved when the while-Construct kicks in.

Is the app just paused in the meantime? If yes, is it possible to realise this with an eventlistner?

Thank you for help!

Comment: Yes, there are synchronous steps here. That is, execution will not continue past a method call while it has not yet returned.

Comment: Ok, but can I add a time, that determines (when elapsed) that the connection failed?

Comment: Check out [setConnectTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout(int))

and [setReadTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setReadTimeout(int))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the app just paused in the meantime?

Yes. The regular Java IO classes are synchronous. The call to `readLine()` will block until either it can return a line or there's an Exception.

> If yes, is it possible to realise this with an eventlistner?

Yes, by using [classes in the `java.nio` package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O). But only with a somewhat lower-level interface.

In general, Java applications use multithreading instead of event qeueues to deal with such sitatuations.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the `BufferedReader` will request its underlying `InputStream` for data every time it is requested to provide data (when you call `reader.readLine()` or any other `readXXX` method on the `BufferedReader`). It's thus the `InputStream`'s responsibility to provide it at that time - which might be possible or not (if the connection was closed, for instance).

In this particular case, the `InputStream` provided by the `URLConnection` will either return data that was cached in a previous read request or request more data from the URL it's pointing to.

As such, no actual data is read until you invoke `readLine` on the `BufferedReader`. You've just opened a connection to the server.